# Does refomatting change my installed drivers?

Tags: ubuntu

I installed or updated nvidia drivers to support 3d or glx (something like that) in my Ubuntu 9.10...and now it's perpetually in Low-Graphics mode.

I tried to fix it but now I just want to do a clean reformat.
**Does reformatting change the drivers back to normal (and rid me of the driver that has plagued my system with "Low-Graphics mode")?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reformatting will **erase** your current filesystem and therefore Ubuntu. Then **re-installing** Ubuntu 9.10 will restore your drivers (and everything else) to the *same state as when you previously did the install*. Make sure you back up any documents and settings you would like to keep beforehand.

Comment: I'm super glad that is that case. Thanks for the answer.